# payload failing at DTO level - nest js

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, dto

I have an incoming payload like below:

```json
{
    "name": "time",
    "value": {
        "from": "USD",
        "to": "CAD"
    }
}
```

but it is not being validated getting destructor error that from does-not exist data basically constructor unable to get value

this is what I have at controller level

```
  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({
    transform: true
  }))
  @UseFilters(new GeneralExceptionFilter())
  public async checkPayload(
    @RabbitPayload() payload: RateDto,
  ): Promise < void > {

  }
```

Following is my dto which is `RateDto`

```
export class RateDto {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    public name: string;

    @ValidateNested()
    @IsObject()
    @Type(() => Pair)
    value: Pair;
}

export interface PairType {
    from: string;
    to: string;
}

export class Pair {

    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @Length(3, 3)
    from: string;

    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @Length(3, 3)
    to: string;

    constructor(data: PairType) {
        const {
            from,
            to
        } = data;
        console.log(from);
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
 }
```